# How to add new field in deserialized objects?

Tags: java, serialization

Having a Class `Employee` with Fields of Employee `Name`, `EmployeeId` and `serialized` it.

Now i have more than `1000` object by doing `deserialization` of that persisted `Employee` class.

Now added New Field `address` in `Employee` Class.

How the new field `address` can be added to the already `deserialized` objects?

**Note :** without doing any `deserialization` again.

Comment: you mean add to the already `serialized` objects?

Comment: Tell us the use case.. why you need that?

Comment: i have modified my employee class by adding new field , but how to get that field included in my already deserialized objects?

Comment: @SheelaXavier, a deserialized object should have all the fields your latest class has. Do you mean to get the field in your serialized objects?

Comment: What is your exact use case? If it's just about compatibility of different versions of `Employee` you should set the `serialVersionUID` to a correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class that extends from your `Employee`.

```
public class EmployeeWithAddr extends Employee {

    private String address;

    public EmployeeWithAddr(Employee employee) {
        //initialize from employee
    }

    public EmployeeWithAddr(Employee employee, String address) {
        //initialize from employee
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() { 
        return address; 
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Then, you take the deserialized object, pass it to the wrapper constructor et voila, you have it.

---

IMHO, there is no need for black magic to change the runtime class and add new fields on objects dynamically. This is good enough.